# Truffle and contract with an Address type constructor parameter

Tags: contract-development, truffle, testrpc, truffle-contract

When I add new contract (testrpc) with truffle with parameter of type "address" the reading value of this property seems wrong (always 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), I do not find the cause of the problem

The Demo.sol contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Demo
{
     address public test;
     function Demo(address test) payable
     {
        test = test;
     }
}
```

I add the new contract with truffle

```
Demo.new("0x9e99b1aaa2114fdae97c9ab2f20863dfde4659bd", {
    from: account,
    value: web3.toWei(0.1, 'ether')
}).then(function (instance) {
    return instance.test.call({from: account});
}).then(function(test) {
    console.log(test);
});
```

The expected result is 0x9e...9bd but the output is 0x00...000.

If necessary, I push the demo project on Github, Thank you for your help

Comment: Where did account come from? Is it defined? Consider dropping it and things should default to first account.

Comment: I use web3.eth.getAccounts... and Metamask opens well to ask for confirmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer to myself... there was a stupid error in the smart contract... The class variable and the parameter had the same name

This code works :

```
 address public myaddress;
 function Demo(address test) payable
 {
    myaddress = test;
 }
```